# ASP.NET/C# client to consume a PHP/MYSQL web service (WSDL)

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, soap, wsdl

I am trying to access a webservice (two files below). The client is using ASP.NET/C# for their web architecture. I can add the web reference but somehow I cannot generate a proxy class for the wsdl file. The aim is to use the function in the server.php file so that I can use the xmlstring to display the data on the ASP.NET website. Any help would be very appreciated. Many Thanks

---

server.php file. This file has a php function which extracts data from a mysql db and the function returns the data as an XML string.

```php
<?php
//WEB SERVICE FUNCTION TO EXTRACT DATA FROM CLIENT B INTO XML FORMAT
function getXML()
{
//CONNECT TO THE DATABASE SERVER
$dbserverIP = "xxxxxxx";
$dbusername = "xxxxxxx";
$dbpassword = "xxxxxxx";
$dbconnection = mysql_connect($dbserverIP,$dbusername,$dbpassword)  
or die ("The connection to the database server failed.");

//CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$dbname = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbselectok = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbconnection)
or die ("The connection to the database failed.");

//QUERY THE DATABASE
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM videogames";
$sqlresult = mysql_query($sqlquery,$dbconnection)
or die ("Error in executing the SQL statement");

//CREATE XML STRING
$xmlstring = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n";
$xmlstring.= "<videogames>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
    $xmlstring .= "\t<game>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<gametitle>" .$row["gametitle"]. "</gametitle>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<genre>" .$row["genre"]. "</genre>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<year>" .$row["year"]. "</year>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<platform>" .$row["platform"]. "</platform>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<agerating>" .$row["agerating"]. "</agerating>\r\n";
        $xmlstring .= "\t\t<price>" .$row["price"]. "</price>\r\n";
    $xmlstring .= "\t</game>\r\n";
}

$xmlstring.= "</videogames>";

//WRITE XML STRING TO EXTERNAL FILE
$filename = "videogames.xml";
$fileaccessmode = "w";
$fptr = fopen($filename,$fileaccessmode);
fwrite($fptr,$xmlstring);
fclose($fptr);

//FREE UP MEMORY
mysql_free_result($sqlresult);
mysql_close($dbconnection);

return $xmlstring;

}

//CODE TO DISABLE THE WSDLE CACHE
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

//DEFINE SOAP SERVER INSTANCE AND RELATED WSDL FILE
//THE service.wsdl FILE IS IN THE SAME FOLDER AS THIS server.php FILE
$server = new SoapServer("service.wsdl");

//ADD FUNCTION TO THE SERVER INSTANCE
$server->addFunction("getXML");

//ACTIVATE THE SOAP HANDLER
$server->handle();

?>
```

This is the WSDL file linked to the server.php file.

```xml
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>

<!-- ====================== DEFINITIONS ====================== -->

<definitions name="MyWebService"
     targetNamespace="http://cet-apache-04.cet.bolton.ac.uk/student/mib1bee/CST3017/assignment/scenario1/service.wsdl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:tns="http://cet-apache-04.cet.bolton.ac.uk/student/mib1bee/CST3017/assignment/scenario1/service.wsdl"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- ====================== TYPES ============================ -->
<!-- No need for type definitions as only xsd built-in ======= --> 
<!-- data types are used                                       -->
<!-- ========================================================= -->

<!-- ====================== MESSAGE ========================== -->

<message name="getXML_Request">
<part name="input" />
</message>

<message name="getXML_Response">
<part name="xmlString" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<!-- ====================== PORT TYPE ============================ -->

<portType name="myWebService_PortType">

<operation name="getXML">
   <input  message="tns:getXML_Request"/>
   <output message="tns:getXML_Response"/>
</operation>

</portType>

<!-- ======================= BINDING ============================= -->

<binding name="myWebService_Binding" type="tns:myWebService_PortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

<operation name="getXML">
   <input>
     <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
</operation>

</binding>

<!-- ======================= SERVICE ============================= -->

<service name="myWebService_Service">
<port name="myWebService_Port" binding="tns:myWebService_Binding">
    <soap:address location="http://cet-apache-04.cet.bolton.ac.uk/student/mib1bee/CST3017/assignment/scenario1/server.php"/>
</port>
</service>

</definitions>
```

Comment: Maybe because I not a specialist in PHP-soap servers, but I was wondering where your XML is converted into a soap-message, with its very specific soap-tags. Your WSDL is declaring a soap service, but your response seems to be an plain XML.

Comment: So to understand this right, the client is C# and the server is PHP? Or is it the other way around? If you're trying to generate a proxy class for a C# client, what is the error when doing so?

Comment: provide code when u creating client in your application

Comment: I still have not fixed this issue. I have gotten as far as creating the web service (simple hello world string) the only problem is when the ASP.NET/C# client is trying to consume the web service the return value is always null for some reason.

Comment: Have you inspected the XML code returned by the server? Is it necessary to write the XML header inside the getXML function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your wsdl:

```
<operation name="getXML">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:MyWebService#getXML"/>
   <input>
     <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
</operation>

</binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just go through this article and you will get a clear picture towards your answers

go to following links:

[php web service to dot net](http://sanity-free.org/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had trouble getting .Net to consume web services created with the wsdl in rpc/literal format. Try converting your WSDL to document/literal format instead and you should have more luck.